# div img src 'title' to form input using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hey all I have a javascript that selects from these img src's and displays in a larger image container. What I need to do now is to take the title of the image that is selected and pass it into a form input.

This is the div:

```
<div class="imgcontainer" id="imgch">
<div class="minicontainer">
    <img src="bl.jpg"   title="blue paper"   class="miniimg" />
    <img src="grey.jpg" title="grey paper" class="miniimg2" />
    <img src="vel.jpg"  title="velum paper" class="miniimg3" />
    <img src="wht.jpg"  title="white paper" class="miniimg" />
</div>
</div>
```

This is the java script i have tried using:

```
<script>
$('#imgch').bind('change click keyup', function() {
$('#imgchange').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

and the form i want it to end up in:

```
 <input type="text"   name="imgchan"  id="imgchange"><br>
```

I am assuming I need to use a similar script but instruct it to take the title specifically but I am not sure how.

As always help massively appreciated :-)

Comment: Not sure how change/keyup work with images/divs.

Comment: So read the title with attr()

Comment: Try `$('#imgchange').val(this.title);`.

Comment: Thanks dfsq unfortunately no joy with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch for clicks on the images *within* the container:

```js
$('#imgch').on('click', 'img', 
   function() {
    $('#imgchange').val( $(this).attr('title') );
   }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imgcontainer" id="imgch">
  <div class="minicontainer">
    <img src="bl.jpg"   title="blue paper"  class="miniimg" />
    <img src="grey.jpg" title="grey paper"  class="miniimg2" />
    <img src="vel.jpg"  title="velum paper" class="miniimg3" />
    <img src="wht.jpg"  title="white paper" class="miniimg" />
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text"   name="imgchan"  id="imgchange"><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) property of the event to get the actually clicked image:

```
$(function () {
  $('#imgch').bind('change click keyup', function(e) {
    $('#imgchange').val($(e.target).attr('title'));
  });
});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v1j23nyy/)

Comment: Thanks thats very useful to know! and thank you for responding :-)